# Syntax for specifying the zero float literal

Tags: c++, syntax, floating-point, language-lawyer, literals

Just find this interesting :-) If you specify `0f`, the value would be interpreted as an octal integer literal. As such, `f` (decimal `15`) is not allowed. `00f` and `.f` don't work either. The only ways that seem to work are `0.f` and `.0f`. Are there any other ways? Still, I can't figure out why `0.f` has worked. Is `0` interpreted as the octal prefix? C++ is surely complex, even the very fundamental syntax ~>_<~

Comment: `f` is not a valid octal literal so I doubt it is being interpreted as one in 0f. see: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84659236f8609846

Comment: I suggest you consulty the documentation on [literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/floating_literal)

Comment: @NathanOliver [clang](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/wgAlNOQOgJfNJALU) seems to suggest that `f` in `0f` is interpreted as decimal `15`.

Comment: What (I believe) I've seen most often is simply `0.0f`, for whatever that's worth. Putting much effort into saving a character or two seems...misguided, at least to me (unless you're doing code golf or something on that order).

Comment: How do you get that.  it says there is an error and f is an invalid octal constant which means `0f != 15` as `0f` is an error.

Comment: @NathanOliver Sorry for my poor English. What I'm trying to say is that the hexadecimal digit `f` (`15` in decimal) is not allowed in octal, and in `0f`, it is not interpreted as the `float` suffix, but the hexadecimal digit `f`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Still, I can't figure out why 0.f

It works, because the `.` character makes it a floating point literal. A floating point literal with `f` is a `float`. The fractional part is optional and zero, if omitted.

Because of the `0.X` syntax for values between 0..1, you cannot have octal floating point literals.

> Is 0 interpreted as the octal prefix?

In case of integer literals yes, `0` prefix is the syntax for octal literal. For example: 01 is octal, 0x1 is hexadecimal, and 1 is decimal.

Comment: So, in `0.x`, the `0` is not interpreted as the octal prefix, but zero?

Comment: @Lingxi yes, the octal prefix applies only to integer literals - the ones without `.`.